# Feign API. Распарсить json response

Tags: json

Есть ли кто-то , кто использовал Feign?  Нужно получить из этого json response
https://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?api_key=WXpCt1X1tDwup2N1YRcBqfI38edEvweb&q=rich
список url-ов для гифок. Строить модель для такого громоздкого ответа прям очень глупо выглядит. Есть ли способы извлечь список url Находящихся в data -> images -> origin -> url ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я это сделал вот так:

```
private String getURL(String gifJson) throws JsonProcessingException {
    return new ObjectMapper().readTree(gifJson).path("data").path("images").path("original").path("url").asText();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
curl -s "https://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?\
    api_key=WXpCt1X1tDwup2N1YRcBqfI38edEvweb&q=rich" |\
    jq -r '.data[].images.original.url' > urls.txt
```

используя инструменты curl и jq